# How can I use a custom mathbf font?

Tags: fonts, bold

My current font configuration is as follows:

```latex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=0.90]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\linespread{1.025}         
\usepackage[T1,euler-digits]{eulervm}
```

Now I prefer the bold symbols (when using `\mathbf`) from the default latex font over those from `mathpazo`. How can I achieve using the default latex font for the `mathbf` environment instead?

**Edit:** With the approach mentioned in the comment section I obtain
[image: How it should look]

[image: how it actually looks]

The first one is without my font config (i.e. only default) and the second one with the approach from the comment. The bold letters are not the same however.

Comment: @campa Yes, this doesn't really yield the correct looking letters.

Comment: Upps, sorry, my bad: `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}`. (`bx` instead of `b` in the fourth argument.)

Comment: @campa Thanks! I guess I'll have to ponder a bit about whether I find this typographically appealing :D

Comment: @Richard Don't do it. Your readers will be grateful. `;-)`